# Ordering Gradle Tasks With finalizedBy and dependsOn

Tags: android, gradle

I have following setup:

```
task A {
  // config for task C
}

task B {
  // config for task C
}

task D {
}
```

Both of these tasks need to be finalized by the task C with the configuration they provided, and B must execute after A. I have adapted then to following

```
A.finalizedBy C
B.finalizedBy C
B.mustRunAfter A
D.dependsOn A, B
```

The issue I'm having with this setup is that when I run `gradle D`:

- Task A is executed, configures task C
- Task B sees that A is finished and executes. B overrides the configuration 
  of C.
- C is only executed for B and not A.

Is there a way to execute a task multiple times? I would need this ordering A -> C -> B -> C.

EDIT:

Following seems to work, but this is not the path I want to take:

```
task A {
  // config for task C
  C.execute()
}

task B {
  // config for task C
  C.execute()
}
```

Comment: could you clarified two strange things in your question: 1) you say that when you run `gradle A` , Gradle executes task `B` : it should not.. there is nothing in your setup that should trigger execution of B when A is executed.  2) normally a  task (here , C) will be executed only once, as explained in this answer https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-execute-tasks-multiple-times-in-a-loop/20160/2  => how did you manage to make task `C` executed twice?

Comment: 1. Thank you for the hint. I forgot to mention that B must run after A.
2. I could be wrong. I thought that it's run 2 times, but as you say, it seems to be only once.

Comment: for 1: `B.mustRunAfter A`  means that when both tasks `A` and `B` are executed, B must run after A (see 
 documentation here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks):  again, if you execute `gradle A`, there is no reason that task `B` is executed.

Comment: can you describe more precisly what is task `C` doing? do you really need to make this job as a Gradle Task ? (maybe you can implement this job as a function/method, invoked by both tasks `A` and `B`). I don't think you will manage to make this task `C` executed twice in a "proper" way (without using `C.execute()` , which is deprecated / not recommanded

Comment: I tried to do that, but unfortunately it is not possible. I decided to resort to executing these tasks separately. Not the most convenient thing, but yeah.. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, Gradle will execute a given task only once during a build.

If you have to do two things, although very similar, then you need two tasks.

The concept of [task rules](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_rules) might help you solve that issue in a generic fashion.